# Ruby rails generate migration commond to add Index on multiple columns in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, migration, addition

I'm new Ruby on Rails. I trying to add index on multiple columns in the existing project. Over the internet I see examples that it can be added as shown below. But I'm not able to understand how to generate migrate script to add the index. Any help would be appreciate.

```
add_index :facility_user_assignments, [:facility_id, :user_id], unique: true.
```

Below is what I found over internet. How can this be changed to add to multiple columns

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToPhoneToUsers phone:string:uniq
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most migrations cannot be generated via the CLI. Instead you should just generate an empty migrate, and fill in the `change` method by hand.

```
rails generate migration AddIndexToPhoneToUsers
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. So instead of using CLI to generating empty migrate, can I directly create below class file:
class AddIndexToFacilityUserAssignmentToUserToFacility < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :facility_user_assignments, [:facility_id, :user_id], unique: true
  end
end

Comment: I tried to add migration class manually as mentioned above. I'm getting error on rake db migrate
 NameError: uninitialized constant AddIndexToFacilityUserAssignmentToUserToFacility

Comment: What is filename of the migration? Does it follow Ruby standard naming convention?

Comment: @sg_developer No, you should not just create a class, you should use the command I included in my answer to generate the file and empty class, so that they are both named consistently and correctly.

Answer (score 2):

use:

`rails generate migration addIndicesToPhone phone:string:uniq`

Then go to your migration file 'add_indices_to_phone.rb' and add what wever fields you want before you migrate.

```
class AddIndicesToPhone < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :phone, :string
    add_column :another_field, :string # add these fields manually
  end

  add_index :phone, :phone, unique: true
  add_index :phone, :another_field, unique: true  # add these fields manually
end
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have columns added in the project, So instead of generating migration file, can I directly create below class file: class AddIndexToFacilityUserAssignmentToUserToFacility < ActiveRecord::Migration def change add_index :facility_user_assignments, [:facility_id, :user_id], unique: true end end